# Map array of strings in state to a select as props?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a parent component with something that looks like the btnColor array below that is set as state:

```
export default class Contact extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        btnColor: ['White', 'Silver', 'Grey', 'Black', 'Orange']
    }
}
```

I also have a child select component that looks like this:

```
const FormSelect = ({
name,
type,
placeholder,
onChange,
className,
value,
error,
children,
label,
btnColor,
...props}) => {

return (
    <div className={className}>
        <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
        <select>
            <option
                id={name}
                name={name}
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                onChange={onChange}
                value={btnColor.map(btnColor)}
            />
        </select>

    </div>
)}
```

What I would like to do is map all items from the btnColor array into the child component and then use them as drop-down options within the FormSelect component.

Ideally looking for an answer that does not involve hooks.  - Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: r u using material UI? 2) is form in child component?Do you want to access the selected option in the parent

Comment: Your `this.state.btnColor` appears to be a string, not an array

Comment: @CodeZombie Yes to all except material UI.

Comment: @evaline - You are correct, I've updated the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would recommend passing a state modifier function to the `<select>` component and adding an event handler for `onchange`.

#### Sample

```
export default class Contact extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        btnColor: '[White, Silver, Grey, Black, Orange, Brown, Maroon, Green, Olive, Red, Cyan, Blue, DarkBlue, LightBlue, Purple, Yellow, Lime, Magenta]',
        submitted: false,
        selected: ''
    }

    selectHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({submitted: true, selected: event.target.value});
    }



    function render() {
        <FormSelect onSelect={onSelect} />
    }
}
```

And the select component:

```
const FormSelect = ({
name,
type,
placeholder,
onChange,
className,
value,
error,
children,
label,
btnColor,
onSelect,
...props}) => {

return (
    <div className={className}>
        <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
        <select onchange={onSelect}>
            <option
                id={name}
                name={name}
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                onChange={onChange}
                value={btnColor.map(btnColor)}
            />
        </select>

    </div>
)}
```

Notice that in the `Contact` component, I have added a new state `selected` which will store the selected value once an event `onchange` is fired.

Comment: thank you, however there is still something wrong with my map function on the value prop.

Answer (score 0):

Here a example how to make those items in array as an options.

```
class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      btnColor: ["White", "Silver", "Grey", "Black", "Orange"],
      submitted: false,
      colorValue: ""
    }; 
  }

  selectHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      colorValue: event.target.value 
    })
  }

 render() {
   const options = this.state.btnColor.map(color => <option key={`${Math.random().toString(26).slice(2)-${color}}} value={color}>{color}</option>);

 return (
  <div>
    <label htmlFor="colorValue">Choose a color:</label>
    <select
      name="colorValue"
      value={this.state.colorValue}
      onChange={selectHandler}
    >
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      {options}
    </select>
  </div>
    );
  }
}
```